# How to Follow HIPAA Compliance in My sails + waterline App?

Tags: sails.js, waterline, hipaa

1. I Need to encrypt all the details(name, email, phone, address) related to patient and doctors for HIPAA Compliance.
2. If data is encrypted then how find query will work ex: I want records from database in the basis of email.